# Adding Web Api Authorization to Existing Razor Pages App

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

I have an asp.net core 2.2 app using Razor Pages and the build in authentication. The app is secured very simply in startup.

```
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/", CO.AdminUserRole);
})
```

.. all works well.
Inside the app, i have some CRUD pages where I have a datatables grid. To edit a record, you click the edit button on the row and I use jquery to pull the details for that particular record from a web api controller.

It all works great. My only issue is that I can type in the /api/[object]/[id] into a web browser and get the data without being an authorised user.

Of course I don't want to have another authorisation process just so i can use the api. Instead, I want to be able to use the existing razor pages authorization state to authorize use of the api.

Posssible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by replacing the webapi with a simple json response from the razor page - using the ideas from this blog post:
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/318/working-with-json-in-razor-pages

this gets me the json output i need, but also secures it as a standard razor page.